# Select query returning Error: ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm new to SQL/PLSQL but very keen on getting up to speed and learning (what seems to be by mistakes currently) so please be gentle.

I have been handed another colleagues PLSQL code to test. I'm coming unstuck in a few areas namely the below.

I am running the following snippet example:

```
    SELECT  cust_code || '_' || substr(p_year_code, 1, 2),      --using this brings an error
-- SELECT  cust_code --using this works fine         
            cust_title,                
            cust_dept_code,
            decode( cust_duration, ':', '0', '', '0',                                       
                    extract(hour from (to_timestamp(cust_duration,'hh24:MI'))) * 60 + 
                    extract(minute from (to_timestamp(cust_duration,'hh24:MI')))
                  ) cust_duration,
            cust_date,
            (CASE                                                                                   
               WHEN cust_date IS NOT NULL THEN                                               
                 to_date(to_char(cust_date,'DD-MM-YYYY') || ' ' || cust_time, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
               ELSE NULL
             END) cust_time,   
            cust_exp_code time_period,
            fw_person_get_desc('PERSON', cust_asmm_code ,null) cust_asmm_desc                        
    FROM    CUST,
            DETAIL
    WHERE   cust_examiner_id = detail_id(+)
    AND     detail_change_ind IS NULL               
    -- AND     cust_start_code <= p_year_code
    -- AND     cust_end_code >= p_year_code
    AND     cust_exp_code IN ('4', '5')
    AND     cust_asmm_code IN ('01', '02', '03', '06', '10')
    AND EXISTS (    SELECT 1 
                    FROM ACTIVITY
                    WHERE activity_asmt_code = cust_code
                    -- AND   activity_code = p_year_code
               );
```

However I get the error ORA-00904: "p_year_code" invalid identifier when i run the code (using TOAD if that helps)
I have access to the tables and the package where p_year_code is referenced (as far as I can see) 
I can run it fine using the commented out lines as detailed

Updated with package details:

```
PROCEDURE pw_process_activity_details (

    p_year_code        IN   cust.cust_start_code%TYPE);
```

Any further knowledge/suggestions on testing SQL/PLSQL would be very much appreciated.

Cheers!
Jake

Comment: seems to me that p_year_code is a parameter from the procedure or function which this sql is part of. If so, check the value being passed to your program and replace p_year_code with it

Comment: Unrelated, but: even Oracle recommends to get rid of the proprietary, outdated outer joins using `(+)`

Comment: Hi GurV, thanks for the quick reply.
p_year_code is running from several procedures within package (pkw_process_schedule) example attached to original post, so i think this may be the case.
I tried your suggestion but struggling a little with the syntax i think. Any examples you could steer me in the right direction with?
Cheers Jake

Comment: Just replace `p_year_code` with `'2016'` or whatever value it would have in the procedure.

Comment: As @GurV mentioned, p_year_code is a parameter that is being passed into this query in the package. Without more information of what's being passed into that parameter, it's impossible to decide what the value should be. Perhaps you can retrieve what p_year_code is by adding a print statement and executing the package itself that calls this procedure: dbms_output.put_line (p_year_code);

Comment: Hi, Thanks @Abdulgood89 I can't view specific detail however from information in notes i can see that it should be either NUMBER(4) or DATE e.g. 2016. I was able to execute the package but errors when the print statement is added. Whether it's rights based i'm not sure.
As i say i'm a bit of a newbie to SQL so apologies if I'm missing something obvious